# screwturn wiki Page Index

Tags: indexing, wiki, screwturn

When viewing All Pages through ScrewTurn Wiki, we have 114 Pages, but the pages are not all combining into one alphabetized list. Pages 1 through 50 have a short alphabetized list, and pages 51- 100 and pages 101 - 114 create a second list of separate pages that form a second alphabetized list.

Clicking on the Page Title Column header does not correct this.  There seems to be no common  difference between the two lists (both have a collection of different page names, Created On dates, Created By, and Categories, and all are in the same namespace.

We've tried rebuilding the index several times, and although this seems to move the list items around, it doesn't combine all the pages into one alphabetized list, which is what we want.

Comment: What version of Screwturn are you using?  My "All Pages" (150+ pages) is sorting by Title where the first letter of the Title is forming a group of pages by that letter.  After clicking on the "Page Title" in All Pages to sort by that column, does your address bar look like this ".../AllPages.aspx?SortBy=Title&Page=0"?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Administration, then Configuration.  Change the value in the setting "Display at most " x "items in a list, then start paging" to a bigger number, and that will sort it for you.

(Edit) Alright, this doesn't technically solve your problem, but it's the best workaround I've found so far!  Basically the index paging doesn't work, so turning it off is the best option.